# Javascript: Calling object methods within that object

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

What is the best design pattern for achieving the following (which doesn't work)?

```
var obj = (function() {

  // code defining private variables and methods

  var _obj = {
    property: value,
    method1: function() {
      // do stuff
    },
    method2: function() {
      // use property
      var prop = _obj.property; // obviously doesn't work
      // call method1
      obj.method1(); // "obj" not finished being defined yet!
    }
  };

  // obviously now I could do...
  var prop = _obj.property;

  return _obj;

})();

// and I could now do...
obj.method1();
```

A variation which I think should work is

```
var obj = (function() {

  var property = value,
      method1 = function() {
        // do stuff
      },
      method2 = function() {
        // use property
        var prop = property;
        // call method1
        method1();
      },
      _obj = {
        property: property,
        method1: method1,
        method2: method2
      };

  return _obj;

})();
```

Similarly, how does it work for objects meant to be created with the `new` operator? Within the constructor function itself you can write `this.method()`. But what if you want to keep the constructor small, only defining those things which will likely be customized upon creation, and then defining the rest in the prototype? (This seems to be the common pattern.) Can the properties / methods within the prototype interact in any way?

```
var MyObj = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};

var obj = new MyObj('Bob');

MyObj.prototype = {
  called_often: function() {
    // lots more code than just the following
    return document.getElementById('someID').value;
  },

  global_default: 'value', // can be changed, so need to pull value when run

  does_stuff: function(value) {
    var str = global_default + value, // can't access global_default on its own
        input = MyObj.called_often(), // doesn't work; MyObj.prototype.called_often() DOES
        name = this.name; // 'this' used in the prototype doesn't work
                          // even within a created object
    return name + input + str;
  }
};
```

I'm sure there's better ways to achieve my result whenever I run into this problem. This code isn't situation specific and just illustrates the general problem. So you won't be able to give me an alternative for those specific situations I run into. But maybe you can help my overall thinking.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Well, from your first example:

```
var _obj = {
    property: value,
    method1: function() {
      // do stuff
    },
    method2: function() {
      // use property
      var prop = this.property; 
      // call method1
      this.method1(); 
    }
  };
```

That's what the `this` value is for.

Now, what you cannot do is refer to a property of an "under construction" object from elsewhere in the object literal syntax.  (It's hard to give an example because it's just not syntactically possible.)  In cases where you want to do that, you do need one or more separate assignment statements.

Comment: I had thought that 'this' only points to the object if it's created with new + constructor, or if you use call/apply. But you're right, it works! Apparently I've been confused this whole time. Also, I had thought I'd tried that. But apparently not.

Comment: JavaScript is amazingly simple and amazingly complicated at the same time :-)  It turns out that `this` is bound at the time a function is called, and that's that; however that simple rule leads to all sorts of interesting details.

Comment: Hi, Pointy. I have same type of issue. I'm using `roundslider.js` and i'm calling a function where you have written do stuff. But It's error for me.
`$("#slider").roundSlider({
change: function(event) {
       traceEvent()
},`
});

Comment: @locateganesh you should probably post your code and describe exactly what's going wrong in your own new question.

Answer (score 11):

Guess what? You are making simple stuff complex. Pointy's answer is good, but the prototype way is better for several reasons. That's why I am describing (rather, making corrections in) the last method. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yAPgW/).

```
var MyObj = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};

MyObj.prototype = {
  called_often: function() {
    // lots more code than just the following
    return 'VALUE'; //document.getElementById('someID').value;
  },

  global_default: 'value', // can be changed, so need to pull value when run

  does_stuff: function(value) {
    var str = this.global_default + value, // can't access global_default on its own
        input = this.called_often(), // doesn't work; MyObj.prototype.called_often() DOES
        name = this.name; // 'this' used in the prototype doesn't work
                          // even within a created object
    return name + input + str;
  }
};

var obj = new MyObj('Bob');
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to throw that into jsfiddle! As I commented on the post above, I apparently was confused about the ability of using 'this' in these situations. (Obviously, as I commented within the prototype version that "this won't work".) I know for sure I tried using this in a prototype before and got an error. Now I'm going to have to revisit that code and see what I was actually doing wrong - because it obviously wasn't the use of 'this'!

Comment: Please note that "this" inside of the an anonymous function refers to the global context. This is not so much related to the fact that we are using "this" inside of the "prototype" object in this example.