# Call js object methods within the object

Tags: javascript

I want to perform a task . JS Object for that is given below

```
var x = {
      _id:"addTwoValue",
      value:function(a,b)
      {
         return manipulate(a) + manipulate(b)
      }
}
```

Now the question is I want to write a function manipulate . How can I write manipulate such that we can call value function.I am pretty new to js

Comment: JSON is a text format, like XML or CSV. You cannot have functions or `var` or anything like that. What you are showing there is a JavaScript object literal, which is quite a different concept.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Calling object methods within that object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918228/javascript-calling-object-methods-within-that-object)

Comment: I was searching for the solution that brk gave !.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes this answers my question, got more clearity after reading this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a json but an object. JSON is text format that makes sharing data easy.You can define `manipulate` as member of the same object

```js
var x = {
  manipulate: function(val) {
    return val * val;
  },
  _id: "addTwoValue",
  value: function(a, b) {
    return this.manipulate(a) + this.manipulate(b)
  }
};

console.log(x.value(2, 4))
```